# Project default is not found

Tags: c#, nuget

Fui instalar um pacote do NuGet e deu erro de `Project default is not found`. Bem, fui no `ComboBox` Default Project para adicionar o projeto que eu quero instalar o pacote e na Combo não lista nada, dstá vazia. Como eu faço para os projetos aparecerem lá? Tenho apenas dois projetos, um SPA que é meu startup e um Class Library chamado Domain. É no Domain que eu quero instalar o pacote(`FluentValidation`).

Comment: Não é só selecionar o projeto no console do Package Manager?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann, como eu faço isso? A combo está vazia.

Comment: Se estiver com a `solution` aberta é só ir no `Package Manager Console` que aparecerá todos os projetos no combo `Default project`. Se está com a solution aberta e não aparece tem algum problema ai.

Comment: Mas é exatamente isso que eu estou postando, não aparece nada.

Answer (score 1):

O `nuget` instalado é compatível com o projeto?

Verifique que versão do Nuget está instalado no seu projeto e quais frameworks suportam ele. Após isso siga os passos abaixo pra ver se resolve:

- Clique com o botão direito no nome do projeto no painel do **Solution
  Explorer** > **Propriedades**.
- Na guia **Application**, mude o **framework** para um mais novo (que suporte a versão do NuGet).
- Feche e tente novamente.

Verifique também se o nome do projeto não está longo demais, parece que isso também pode ocasionar o problema.

Comment: aeu estava com dois VS abertos, pois precisava do outro para entender o modelo DDD.Bem, fechei esse e mesmo assim não rodou. Fechei tudo, restartei e ao subir o VS funcionou. Não sei o que aconteceu.